# Disable (make read-only) text input on mat-datepicker when using a reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular Material 2's `mat-datepicker` and want the input element disabled so the user cannot edit the value using the text input.

There are [detailed instructions in the Angular Material 2 docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#disabling-parts-of-the-datepicker) on how to disable different parts of the `mat-datepicker` however, these do not seem to cover how to disable the text input when it is part of a reactive form.

The Angular Material docs suggest you disable the text input in the following way:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <!-- Add the disabled attribute to the input element -->
  <input
    disabled
    matInput
    [matDatepicker]="dateJoined"
    placeholder="Date joined"
    formControlName="dateJoined"
  >
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateJoined"></mat-datepicker-toggle>

  <!-- Add [disabled]=false to the mat-datepicker -->                  
  <mat-datepicker
    [disabled]="false"
    startView="year"
    #dateJoined
  ></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

However, if your datepicker is part of a reactive form the text element remains active and you get the following  message from Angular:

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
> directive. If you set disabled to true when you set up this control in
> your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in
> the DOM for you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed
> after checked' errors.
> Example:
> form = new FormGroup({ first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true})});

I updated the `FormGroup` in the component to disable the `FormControl`, which has the desired effect of disabling the input, however, if you then get the value of the `FormGroup` using `this.form.value` the disabled form control is no longer present.

**Is there a work around for this which does not involve having a separate template driven form using `ngModel` just for the mat-datepicker(s)?**

**EDIT:** added “read-only” to post title to clarify this isn’t about disabling the control - because what I was asking about was to make the input element read-only, but not disable to control itself

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To create a disabled `FormControl` is really simple.

1 - Don't use disabled attribute in your template;

2 - Instantiate your `FormGroup` like this:

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  dateJoined: { disabled: true, value: '' }
  // ...
});
```

---

That being said, although you want to prevent users from typing something in the input, you still want to let them select a date by clicking the button (more specifically in `matSuffix`), right?

If it's correct, `disable` doesn't work for this case, because it'll disable all the input (including the button in `matSuffix`).

To solve your case, you can use `readonly`. Instantiate the `FormGroup` normally and then in template:

```
<input                          
  matInput 
  readonly <- HERE
  [matDatepicker]="dateJoined" 
  placeholder="Date joined" 
  formControlName="dateJoined">
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-ty6jzr)</kbd>

Comment: Is there a solution from where you get that input style like the disabled one? Because the input with readonly only prevents editing, but does not change the style like in the material example with non-reacitve forms.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to enable it programmatically on some action?

Comment: @PushkarKathuria See answer below for how to programmatically enable/disable `readonly`.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on [developer033's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47342068/1164465), to dynamically toggle the `readonly` state of the `input`, modify the `readonly` property using a component variable.

## Dynamically Toggle Readonly

##### See [**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-so-47341535-pe8vs6-287ubj)

#### app.component.html

```
<input matInput 
  [readonly]="inputReadonly"   <!-- Update `readonly` property using variable -->
  [matDatepicker]="dateJoined" 
  placeholder="Date joined" 
  formControlName="dateJoined">
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {VERSION} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  inputReadonly = true;
  version = VERSION;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      dateJoined: ''
    });
  }

  public toggleInputReadonly() {
    this.inputReadonly = !this.inputReadonly;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Always great to point out that you can make the values of attributes dynamic when you need to.

Comment: This works. I do not understand though, why the hover highlight when you place the mouse cursor on top of it while it is readonly. shouldn't it be disabled as well?

Answer (score 1):

This helped us to disable input:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Input disabled</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp3" disabled>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dp3 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

[Ref](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it made it clear I needed to clarify the title. What I was after was how to make the input element read only, but not disable the control